# Why camera does not have a USB port to connect to PowerBank for power?

Tags: power

I notice that almost all camera use either a proprietary Li-ion battery or AA size battery for power.

May I know what is the reason for not having a camera that have USB port that can be connect to a Power Bank for supply? (since there are so many Power Bank of different mAh nowadays)

Comment: Sony cameras charge batteries when connected to a standard micro-USB connector, although they cannot function as a camera and charge at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Charging the camera battery inside the camery is a heat issue - batteries get warm to hot while getting charged, and the camera electronics, especially the sensor, would have issues with that.

Operating the camera with a cable and a power bank dangling is also not a typical use case, as you move around and hold the camera up.

Most cameras can be connected to main power with a cable if they are operated stationary (but that doesn't charge the battery - see above why)